# Disable vertical scrolling while scrolling horizontally

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, parallax

I'm looking for an easy way to do the same as this web site :

http://wildbluetech.com/

(section culture)

I want to disable the vertical scroll while I'm scrolling horizontal. When I finished the section, i want to enable the vertical scroll. And I want it to work reversly too

Comment: There is no "easy" way, that's why developpers are hirable!

Comment: But if it can help you, this site use this plug-in : http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I know, there is not an "easy" way, but there's a solution for sure. I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: Also this one : http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

it is easy:

You should learn parallax, it is working with scroll function in jquery and you set the div css position fix when scroll is on (for example) 100px from top, and change other div horizontally